# How to resize images inserted before <li> tags using pseudo-classes relative to the <li> font-size?

Tags: css, html-lists, pseudo-class

I want to create a 500px by 500px image template that can be used to create custom listpoints, with the symbol always being 500px wide and centered in the middle.

Now I want to automatically insert the image before every `<li>` element and have it sized relative to the size of the `<li>` font-size (so using 1em).

Using size:1em, has no effect at all on the image inserted via "content:". I've tried to use the image as a background-image, which works, but than for some reason the size does not match the font size, even if both are set to 1em - the image is smaller and the error doesn't hit the middle of a uppercase letter.

I also want to second lines of the `<li>` elements to automatically have the same indent as the first line.

Here's my example code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#test {
    max-width: 698px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:2em;}


#test ul {
    margin:0em;}    

#test li {
    font-size:1em;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:central;
    padding:5em 0em;
    margin:0em;
}
#test li::before{
    content: url(https://s16.postimg.org/ia5m43u3p/redarrow.png); 
    /*https://s13.postimg.org/y94150zmf/redheart.png */
    /* size:1em; (not working) */
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test">

<ul>
<li>text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it?</li>
<li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
<li>It is a long established fact that a reader</li>
</ul>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my Code using the image as a background-image

```
    <html>
<head>
<style>
#test {
    max-width: 698px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:2em;}


#test ul {
    margin:0em;}    

#test li {
    font-size:1em;
    list-style:none;
    padding:5em 0em;
    margin:0em;
}
#test li::before{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://s16.postimg.org/ia5m43u3p/redarrow.png);
     /* alternative redheart icon:  https://s13.postimg.org/y94150zmf/redheart.png */
     background-size:contain;
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;


}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="test">

<ul>
<li>text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it?</li>
<li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
<li>It is a long established fact that a reader</li>
</ul>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: width and height have no effect on inline elements. Add `display:inline-block` for the pseudo element.

Comment: tried this, but neither width or size have any effect on the image inserted via `content:url(...)`

Comment: Size the pseudo element to the dimensions you need, and then apply the image as background-image (content becomes just `content: "";` then, because without content no pseudo element). Then you can use background-size on it if needed.

Comment: Thanks, but that's exactly the problem. If I use this method the Font is set to 1em relative to it's container. The image is rectangular. The content ::before is set to 1em relative to it's container, but still the arrow doesn't line up as it should, it should be the same size as the font and hit a uppercase letter in the middle, but it doesn't.

Comment: Well that's more likely a problem with the image you are using. But adjusting the background-position a bit (can also be done in em, resp. fractions thereof) should fix that ...

Comment: I got it to work if the size/height of the background is set to 0.9em or 0.8. But the image does not have an error, it's 500x500 and the arrow is centered perfectly. In theory, if the div has a font-size of 14px and then the li is 1em and the image/background should also scale to the 1em, it should be scaled down to 14px, but it just doesn't. guess it's some kind of bug

Comment: Not a bug, rather just not properly defined vertical-align. So go and try the different values for that property, and see what that results in.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using flex can help?

```css
#test {
    max-width: 698px;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:2em;
  font-size: 14px;
}


#test ul {
    margin:0em;}    

#test li {
    font-size:1em;
    list-style:none;
    padding:5em 0em;
    margin:0em;
    display:flex;
}
#test li::before{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    background-image: url(https://s16.postimg.org/ia5m43u3p/redarrow.png);
     /* alternative redheart icon:  https://s13.postimg.org/y94150zmf/redheart.png */
     background-size:contain;
    height:1em;
    width:1em;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    flex:0 0 1em;
    vertical-align: bottom;
  margin-right: 10px
}
```

```html
   
<div id="test">

<ul>
<li>text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it?</li>
<li>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</li>
<li>It is a long established fact that a reader</li>
</ul>


</div>
```